# c# get attributes from object

Tags: c#

I'm a bit new to C# and I got this script that gets a record from a mssql database. There it converts the key to an object.

Its:

```
Object obj = result[i];
```

When I enable a breakpoint on the line after the declaration I see the data that is inside the object. Now I need to access the attribute with the data but because Im a bit new to C# I dont know how to do that.

Lets say the attribute is called: name
I made a new class of my own also with the attribute name.

When I try to get the name of the key to my object with:

```
myObject.Name = (string) obj.Name;
```

The IDE already gives an error that the attribute in the obj isnt available.

How can I access the name attribute of the object to get it to my own object?

Thanks!

Comment: What does result[i] contain exactly? You say you've loaded a record from the database, but in what format is it returned?

Comment: With C#'s terminology, .Name is a property, not an attribute. Attribute has other meanings in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `result[i]` is an instance of your class (which I'll call `Foo` for convenience)? Then you can say

```
Foo obj = result[i];
myObject.Name = obj.Name;
```

or

```
Object obj = result[i];
myObject.Name = ((Foo)obj).Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your object to proper type. E.g. if your object is:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

than you need to cast it like:

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject)result[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to access an attribute of the `Object` class, and it has no attributes.  You either have to **[cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** your `obj` to the class that you created, the one that has the `Name` attribute, or (more simply), when reading the database read it directly into an instance of your class, something like:

`MyClass obj = result[i]`

Answer (score 0):

What data is present in `result[i]`?  Is it just a string from a field in the record in the database?  (That is, is `result` a `DataRow`?)  As it stands, you're placing it inside of just an `Object` which doesn't know much about it.  Basically, you're "boxing" it and removing knowledge of the object's data from the compiler.

If `result[i]` is just a string, try something like:

```
myObject.Name = System.Convert.ToString(result[i]);
```

Now, this is fairly beginner in that there are other considerations to be made here.  If `result[i]` is ever `null` then this will throw an exception, etc.  But while you're learning this should get the data you're looking for.